# Validate Xml with Xsd and update Xml

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

i am validating a Xml file with an existing Xsd schema. Is it possible to update the Xml with the xsd file if the validation fails?

Comment: You could pass it through a customised XSLT which copies valid nodes, fixes bad data, excludes unknown nodes and adds missing nodes. Or do you mean to do this entirely generically, for any XSD?

Comment: Hi, the story behind is, that i have a Xml config file stored locally. When I want to update my config file I only have to change the Xsd file which is in my project and publish it. On program startup my code is validating the xml file with the new Xsd file and if there is an error the xml file will be updated. Or is there a better solution for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Error you can execute this code

```
var schemaSet = new XmlSchemaSet();  
schemaSet.Add(null, "schema1.xsd");  
// add further schemas as needed  
schemaSet.Compile();  

var xmlSampleGenerator= new XmlSampleGenerator(schemaSet, new XmlQualifiedName("Test"));  

var doc = new XmlDocument();  
using (XmlWriter writer = doc.CreateNavigator().AppendChild())  
{  
   xmlSampleGenerator.WriteXml(writer);  
}
```

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302296.aspx

Comment: So the only way here is to create a new xml file from the xsd? It is not possible to edit the old one with some already saved values?

Comment: Yes you can it's possible, but your must compare your file line by line,  i suggest you to save new version of file with logging information